# Typescript, and typeorm problems

Tags: sql, typescript, sqlite, syntax, typeorm

`QueryFailedError: SQLITE_ERROR: near "Jan": syntax error.` This makes no sense to me at all i have done anything like i have before but this time its seems like its saying it being to slow or something.

Comment: What is the SQL that is throwing the error?

Comment: query failed: CREATE TABLE "infractions" ("id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "guild" bigint NOT NULL, "moderator" bigint NOT NULL, "target" bigint NOT NULL, "reason" varchar NOT NULL, "time" date NOT NULL DEFAULT (Sun Jan 12 2020 16:17:20 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its throwing an error because of the default on your `time` column.

I'd suggest taking a look at that. Changing the default to `date('now')` (as you've tagged sqlite) should do the trick, depending on your use case